# Need to replace or condition for performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have below where condition in my query

```
WHERE ( Identifier LIKE '100' + '%' OR ( 1 = 1
     AND  (right(Identifier,4) LIKE '100' + '%'  OR ISNULL(Identifier,'') = '' )
     AND  ID IN (1,4)
    ))
```

Because of where condition my statistics are getting high and this query is written in dynamically so when condition satisfices this clause call

I am looking to change OR clause but not getting how ?

I have tried with case statement but not sure will work

```
where case when '%' + Identifier LIKE '100' + '%' when (right(Identifier,4) LIKE '100' + '%' then ISNULL(Identifier,'') = ''
```

Using sql server 2016

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [Schema].[Main](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Identifier] [varchar](20) NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Main] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Index definition

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Main] ON [Schema].[Main]
(
    [TaxIdentifier] ASC
)
```

Statistics Count

[image]

Comment: We'd need to see the table definition (including indexes) and the query plan to be able to properly advise you.  Also the rest of the query.  Just fiddling around with this WHERE condition isn't likely to be enough.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I have added definitions

Comment: `ISNULL(Identifier,'') = ''` isn't going to be good for performance, just use `IS NULL`. Unfortunately there is little you can do about `right(Identifier,4) LIKE '100' + '%'`; not without a design change to the table. As for `1 = 1`, why is that there? When does 1 not equal 1?

Comment: @Larnu the redundant 1=1 condition is a typical shortcut when the WHERE clauses are procedurally generated.  The optimizer factors them out anyway resulting in no execution time impact.

Comment: It *should* factor them out, but that doesn't mean it should be there, @RBarryYoung . It's also not the first clause, which is where you would normally see it. It certainly should *not* be in an `OR` clause though.

Comment: Well the OR clause part I’d agree with.

Comment: `right(Identifier,4) LIKE '100' + '%'` is more succinctly written as `Identifier LIKE '%100_'`, but this will not improve the performance -- a `LIKE` pattern on the end of a string can't use an index seek. You could separate out `RIGHT(Identifier, 4)` as a computed column and index that, though, or even create a filtered index. The `ISNULL` anti-pattern should be removed; see [this article](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for an in-depth treatment of how to do dynamic search conditions properly.

Comment: A possible solution to a badly performing `OR` is to `UNION ALL` i.e. create 2 selects, 1 for each condition and `UNION ALL` them together.